# How can I prevent text within div with position: absolute from wrapping in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to put two divs beside each other within a container that has absolute positioning.  In chrome and IE it works fine but in Firefox (version 42) the text unexpectedly wraps.  See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b5gqveo4/ .

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>

        .container {
            position:absolute;
            left:100px;
            top: 100px;
        }

        .float-left {
            float: left;
            width: 20px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        .text {
            padding: 3px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="float-left">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="text">text here wraps in firefox but not chrome</div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Adding white-space: nowrap; does not work.  This causes the last word to be chopped off in Firefox.  Also I want the text to wrap when it's too long to fit otherwise.

Why does it wrap in Firefox and how can I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `p.test {text-wrap:none;}`?

Comment: if you add `width: 293px` to container it will be the same. I think the problem might be how each browser rendering the width differently. https://jsfiddle.net/b5gqveo4/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the text does not wrap, add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.text` container.

Comment: This doesn't work (last word gets chopped off) and I want the text to wrap when it hits the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option:

1. Set width of the Container div to longer: 300px or 100%, etc...
2. You can set style : white-space: nowrap for the div with class text (not for container div).In your example beacause you not set width for the .text div, if white-space is nowrap so the text will be hidden, because your style is: overflow: hidden.You can remove the overflow-hidden css for .text to see clearly